# Contravariance vs Covariance in Scala

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I just learned Scala. Now I am confused about Contravariance and Covariance.

From this [page](http://www.stephanboyer.com/post/39/covariance-and-contravariance), I learned something below:

Covariance

Perhaps the most obvious feature of subtyping is the ability to replace a value of a wider type with a value of a narrower type in an expression. For example, suppose I have some types `Real`, `Integer <: Real`, and some unrelated type `Boolean`. I can define a function `is_positive :: Real -> Boolean` which operates on `Real` values, but I can also apply this function to values of type `Integer` (or any other subtype of `Real`). This replacement of wider (ancestor) types with narrower (descendant) types is called `covariance`. The concept of `covariance` allows us to write generic code and is invaluable when reasoning about inheritance in object-oriented programming languages and polymorphism in functional languages.

However, I also saw something from somewhere else:

```
scala> class Animal     defined class Animal

scala> class Dog extends Animal     defined class Dog

scala> class Beagle extends Dog     defined class Beagle

scala> def foo(x: List[Dog]) = x     foo: (x: List[Dog])List[Dog] // Given a List[Dog], just returns it      

scala> val an: List[Animal] = foo(List(new Beagle))     an: List[Animal] = List(Beagle@284a6c0)
```

Parameter `x` of `foo` is `contravariant`; it expects an argument of type `List[Dog]`, but we give it a `List[Beagle]`, and that's okay

[What I think is the second example should also prove `Covariance`. Because from the first example, I learned that "apply this function to values of type `Integer` (or any other subtype of `Real`)". So correspondingly, here we apply this function to values of type `List[Beagle]`(or any other subtype of `List[Dog]`). But to my surprise, the second example proves `Cotravariance`]

I think two are talking the same thing, but one proves `Covariance` and the other `Contravariance`. I also saw [this question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321921/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala-java). However I am still confused. Did I miss something or one of the examples is wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That you can pass a `List[Beagle]` to a function expecting a `List[Dog]` is nothing to do with contravariance of functions, it is still because List is covariant and that `List[Beagle]` is a `List[Dog]`.

Instead lets say you had a function:

```
def countDogsLegs(dogs: List[Dog], legCountFunction: Dog => Int): Int
```

This function counts all the legs in a list of dogs. It takes a function that accepts a dog and returns an int representing how many legs this dog has.

Furthermore lets say we have a function:

```
def countLegsOfAnyAnimal(a: Animal): Int
```

that can count the legs of any animal.  We can pass our `countLegsOfAnyAnimal` function to our `countDogsLegs` function as the function argument, this is because if this thing can count the legs of any animal, it can count legs of dogs, because dogs are animals, this is because functions are contravariant.

If you look at the definition of `Function1` (functions of one parameter), it is

```
trait Function1[-A, +B]
```

That is that they are contravariant on their input and covariant on their output.  So `Function1[Animal,Int] <: Function1[Dog,Int]` since `Dog <: Animal`

Comment: Good explanation. The return type of `groomAnyAnimal` should be `Dog` to plug it in though, as functions are covariant in their return type and contravariant only in their argument type.

Comment: @stew so do you think the second example's statements are somehow wrong?

Comment: @CSnerd In your second example, you somehow want to make a statement about whether `x` is covariant or contravariant. However, as stew mentioned, variance has nothing to do about whether you can pass a subtype where a supertype is required (see [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). The only thing covariant in your second example is `List`, hence  `List[Beagle]` is a subtype of `List[Dog]`.

Comment: @Kulu Limpa thanks for your reply, actually the second example is from PPT of my lecture. I just want to make sure whether its statements are somehow wrong or my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @CSnerd So is everything clear now? If not, it is probably better discussed in a chat.

Comment: @Kulu Limpa yeah, I think so. The statements from PPT are misleading. Now I am clear. Thanks:)

Answer (score 19):

A Good recent article (August 2016) on that topic is "**[Cheat Codes for Contravariance and Covariance](https://www.originate.com/cheat-codes-for-contravariance-and-covariance/)**" by **[Matt Handler](https://twitter.com/matthandlersux)**.

It starts from the general concept as presented in "**[Covariance and Contravariance of Hosts and Visitors](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/JavaResources/generics/co_contra_host_visitor.html)**" and diagram from [**Andre Tyukin**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707792/andrey-tyukin) and [**anoopelias**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1328888/anoopelias)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/6309).

[image: http://blog.originate.com/images/variance.png]

And its concludes with:

> Here is how to determine if your `type ParametricType[T]` can/cannot be covariant/contravariant:
>
> - **A type can be covariant when it does not call methods on the type that it is generic over**.
>     If the type needs to call methods on generic objects that are passed into it, it cannot be covariant.
>
> Archetypal examples:

```
Seq[+A], Option[+A], Future[+T]
```

> - **A type can be contravariant when it does call methods on the type that it is generic over**.
>     If the type needs to return values of the type it is generic over, it cannot be contravariant.
>
> Archetypal examples:

```
`Function1[-T1, +R]`, `CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To]`, `OutputChannel[-Msg]`
```

Regarding contravariance,

> **Functions are the best example of contravariance**
>   (note that they’re **only contravariant on their arguments**, and they’re actually **covariant on their result**).
>   For example:

```
class Dachshund(
  name: String,
  likesFrisbees: Boolean,
  val weinerness: Double
) extends Dog(name, likesFrisbees)

def soundCuteness(animal: Animal): Double =
  -4.0/animal.sound.length

def weinerosity(dachshund: Dachshund): Double =
  dachshund.weinerness * 100.0

def isDogCuteEnough(dog: Dog, f: Dog => Double): Boolean =
  f(dog) >= 0.5
```

> Should we be able to pass `weinerosity` as an argument to `isDogCuteEnough`? The answer is no, because the function `isDogCuteEnough` only guarantees that it can pass, at most specific, a `Dog` to the function `f`.
>   When the function `f` expects something more specific than what `isDogCuteEnough` can provide, it could attempt to call a method that some `Dogs` don’t have (like `.weinerness` on a `Greyhound`, which is insane).

Answer (score 4):

Variance is used to indicate **subtyping** in terms of **Containers**(eg: `List`). In most of the languages, if a function requests object of Class Animal, passing any class that inherits `Animal`(eg: `Dog`) would be valid. However, in terms of Containers, these need not be valid.
If your function wants `Container[A]`, what are the possible values that can be passed to it? If `B` extends `A` and passing `Container[B]` is valid, then it is **Covariant**(eg: `List[+T]`). If, A extends B(the inverse case) and passing `Container[B]` for `Container[A]` is valid, then it is **Contravariant**. Else, it is invariant(which is the default). You could refer to an article where I have tried explaining variances in Scala
https://blog.lakshmirajagopalan.com/posts/variance-in-scala/