# Contravariance why is the subtype?

Tags: scala, contravariance

I am trying to understand **contravariance**, how it works. Consider following sentence:

> Confusingly, contravariance means that the type F[B] is a subtype of
>   F[A] if A is a subtype of B

The sentence makes me confuse. On the first part `F[B] is subtype of F[A]` and suddenly why on the second part is `A is a subtype of B`? It contradicts itself?

Covariance is more clear:

> Covariance means that the type F[B] is a subtype of the type F[A] if B
>   is a subtype of A .

On the first part is **F[B] is subtype** and also on the second **B is subtype**.

Comment: That's it. Covariance is the "natural" for our understanding. Contravariance means that F[B] is subtype of F[A] while A is subtype of B.

A and F[A] are different things, so it's not contradictory, it's just confusing :)

You can check this answer, I think it's pretty helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414991/contravariance-vs-covariance-in-scala

Comment: `JsonWriter[Shape] is a subtype of JsonWriter[Circle] because Circle is a
subtype of Shape` for me it does not make sense at all.

Comment: Contravariance is the 'other direction' to covariance, another way to state the above would be `contravariance means F[B] is a subtype of F[A] if A is a supertype of B`.

Comment: Is contravariance really that surprising? There are many things that contravary, that you don't think twice about. For example, the value and the absolute magnitude of a negative number are contravariant: as the value gets larger, the magnitude gets smaller and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Json example in the comments of this question:

```
trait Shape {
  val area: Double
}

case class Circle(radius: Double) extends Shape {
  override val area = math.Pi * radius * radius
}

def writeJson(circles: List[Circle], jsonWritingFunction: Circle => String): String =
  circles.map(jsonWritingFunction).mkString("\n")

def circleWriter(circle: Circle): String =
  s"""{ "type" : "circle writer", radius : "${circle.radius}", "area" : "${circle.area}" }"""

def shapeWriter(shape: Shape): String =
  s"""{ "type" : "shape writer", "area" : "${shape.area}" }"""
```

Then both of these are acceptable:

```
writeJson(List(Circle(1), Circle(2)), circleWriter)
writeJson(List(Circle(1), Circle(2)), shapeWriter)
```

And result in

```
// first writeJson
{ "type" : "circle writer", "radius" : "1.0", "area" : "3.141592653589793" }
{ "type" : "circle writer", "radius" : "2.0", "area" : "12.566370614359172" }
// first writeJson
{ "type" : "shape writer", "area" : "3.141592653589793" }
{ "type" : "shape writer", "area" : "12.566370614359172" }
```

Even though `jsonWritingFunction` expects a `Circle => String` we can pass it a `Shape => String` due to `Function1`'s declaration: `trait Function1[-T1, +R]`. The first type (`T1`) is contravariant.

Hence `Shape => String` is a subtype of `Circle => String` because `Circle` is a subtype of `Shape`.

Comment: Your last sentence sounds contradicted to me, it sounds for me, first is `shape` a subtype of `circle` and on the second time `circle` is a subtype of `shape`, so that makes me confused.

Comment: "first is `shape` a subtype of `circle`" - this isn't true because you _cannot_ take it out of context of the complex type. You _have to_ say `Shape => String` is a subtype of `Circle => String`, you can't just get rid of the `=> ...` stuff. (It is confusing, but it's no coincidence that **contra**dictory and **contra**variance share the same prefix!)

Answer (score 1):

I have an intuition that I find helpful to understand covariance and contravariance. Note that this is not a strict definition though. The intuition is following:

1. if some class only outputs values of the type `A`, which is the same as saying that the users of the class can only read values of the type `A` from the class, it is covariant in the type `A`
2. if some class only takes values of the type `A` as inputs, which is the same as saying that the users of the class can only write values of the type `A` to the class, it is contravariant in the type `A`

For a simple example consider two interfaces `Producer[A]` and `Consumer[A]`:

```
trait Producer[A] {
   def produce():A
}

trait Consumer[A] {
   def consume(value:A):Unit
}
```

One just outputs values of type `A` (so you "read" `A` from `Producer[A]`) while the other accepts them as a parameter (so you "write" `A` to the `Producer[A]`).

Now consider method `connect`:

```
def connect[A](producer:Producer[A], consumer:Consumer[A]): Unit = {
  val value = producer.produce()
  consumer.consume(value)
}
```

If you think for a moment this `connect` is not written in the most generic way. Consider types hierarchy `Parent` <: `Main` <: `Child`.

1. For a fixed `Consumer[Main]` it can process both `Main` and `Child` because any `Child` is actually `Main`. So `Consumer[Main]` can be safely connected to both `Producer[Main]` and `Producer[Child]`.
2. Now consider fixed `Producer[Main]`. It produces `Main`. Which `Consumer`s can handle that? Obviously `Consumer[Main]` and `Consumer[Base]` because every `Main` is `Base`. However `Consumer[Child]` can't safely handle that because not every `Main` is `Child`

So one solution to creating the most generic `connect` would be to write it like this:

```
def connect[A <: B, B](producer:Producer[A], consumer:Consumer[B]): Unit = {
  val value = producer.produce()
  consumer.consume(value)
}
```

In other words, we explicitly say that there are two different generic types `A` and `B` and one is a parent of another.

Another solution would be to modify `Producer` and `Consumer` types in such a way that an argument of type `Producer[A]` would accept any `Producer` that is safe in this context and similarly that an argument of type `Consumer[A]` would accept any `Consumer` that is safe in this context. And as you may have already noticed the rules for `Producer` are "covariant" but the rules for "Consumer" are "contravariant" (because remember you want `Consumer[Base]` to be a safe subtype of `Consmer[Main]`). So the alternative solution is to write:

```
trait Producer[+A] {
   def produce():A
}

trait Consumer[-A] {
   def consume(value:A):Unit
}

def connect[A](producer:Producer[A], consumer:Consumer[A]): Unit = {
  val value = producer.produce()
  consumer.consume(value)
}
```

This solution is better because it covers all cases by a single change. Obviously in any context that `Consumer[Main]` is safe to be used `Consumer[Base]` is also safe.