# Scala inheritance in function signature

Tags: scala, inheritance, scala-2.10

I have

```
trait X {

}

class Y extends X

Trait A{ def run(x:X){ /////// } }

Class B extends A{ def run(y:Y) }
```

However scala complains at B's `run` function

I am confused on how method signature works inheritance.  class B should have a method of signature X, but Type Y is a Type X.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Covariance and Contravariance in Scala, java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321921/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods are contravariant in their argument types. Let me take your example and explain:

```
val b: B = new B
val y: Y = new Y

b.run(y) // everything is ok

val a: A = b // B is A
val x: X = new X {}

a.run(x) // run on A takes an X. x is of type X
// But: B only takes a Y (more specific type) --> Boom
```

Let me formulate this in words: In order to support the interface defined in `A`, `B` needs to be able to work with **any** `X` in its `run` method. So you cannot know for sure the `X` it is going to get is also a `Y`.

Note that you are actually allowed to do the opposite:

```
class B extends A { def run(x: Any) = /* snip */ }
```

Since `B` accepts any value in its run method, it also accepts an `X`, so everything is fine.

It is interesting to see, that return values are the other way around:

```
trait A {
  def foo: X
}

class B extends A {
  def foo: Y = /* snip */
}
```

This is valid, since `B` just has to return some `X`. Any `Y` is also a `X`, so we are good.

I hope this made it a bit clearer what is going on here and why the compiler forbids you implement your methods that way.

Comment: following your explanation, if B implements run(Any), then B still needs to implement run(X), because run(x) in class A was abstract. I also tried the revers, define an abstract run(any) in A, but then B will require a run(Any)

Comment: If `B` implements `run(Any)` it already has implemented `run(X)`, since every `X` is also a `Any`. Therefore, the method `run(Any)` is able to handle  it as well.