# Unable to understand contravariance wrt Function1(-T1,+T1)

Tags: scala

I am unable to understand contravariance wrt functiontype 1. The definition of function type1 is as below :

Function1(-T,+T)

The definition clearly says the input type parameter is contravariance. So a superclass type of a type should be allowed as parameter.  But why is this giving compiler error.

I have defined below classes

```
 class Animal 
  class Mammal extends Animal 
  class Cow extends Mammal
```

I have defined method as below

```
def move(m:Mammal) = Unit c
```

When I am invoking move like in below it gives no error

```
 move (new Cow)
```

but this gives error

```
move(new Animal)
```

Why is that I am not able invoke move() with Animal as param even though Function1 is contravariant[-T] .

I am new to Scala, so please help me out in this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isn't the argument type co- not contra-variant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321921/isnt-the-argument-type-co-not-contra-variant)

Answer (score 2):

Contravariance does not mean that the function can be provided with a value of "lower" type, but that when comparing the types of two functions

```
type F = Function1(A, B)
type G = Function1(C, B)
```

then if `A` is a *super* type of `C` then `F` is a *sub* type of `G`. In essence, the ordering (variance) on types of functions goes against (contra) the ordering of the types in their input positions.

In particular if you imagine a function:

```
def foo(f : Cow => String) : String = f(new Cow)
```

Then from the perspective of the body of `foo`, `f` can accept a `Cow`, but then, from the perspective of the caller to `foo`, a function that accepts `Animal` would also accept `Cow` just fine, so it makes sense to allow that:

```
foo((a : Animal) => "generic animal noise")
foo((c : Cow) => "moo")
```

In English, the contract for the function `foo` is:

> Give me a thing that when I provide it a `Cow`, I get given back a `String`, and in return, I will give you a `String`.

And in particular, a function that when given an `Animal` provides a `String`, fits the bill for "a thing that when given a `Cow`, returns a `String`".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the nature of can be intuitively understood: you cannot pass instance of Animal to move, because function move may rely on some method which is defined in Mammal but is missing in Animal.

Hope this helps